UB or not UB, concurrently operating on static memory in Rust
I have a piece of Rust code where two threads access and modify the same static usize using raw mutable pointers. The operations performed on the value are bitwise and non-atomic, but the logic ensures only one thread writes to the memory location at a time, based on a conditional check.
Here’s the code:
use std::time::Duration;

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct StaticNumber(*mut usize);
unsafe impl Send for StaticNumber {}

fn main() {
    let number = StaticNumber(Box::leak(Box::new(usize::MAX)) as *mut usize);

    let t1 = std::thread::spawn(move || thread1(number));
    let t2 = std::thread::spawn(move || thread2(number));

    let _ = t1.join();
    let _ = t2.join();
}

fn thread1(number: StaticNumber) {
    loop {
        if unsafe { *number.0 } & 1 == 0 {
            unsafe { *number.0 |= 1 };
        } else {
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        }
    }
}

fn thread2(number: StaticNumber) {
    loop {
        if unsafe { *number.0 } & 1 == 1 {
            unsafe { *number.0 &= usize::MAX << 1 };
        } else {
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        }
    }
}

The core idea is as follows:

Each thread reads the least significant bit (LSB) of the usize value.
Based on the LSB, one thread sets it to 1, while the other resets it to 0.
The application logic ensures that the state read by each thread is eventually consistent, as both threads check the LSB before attempting to modify the value.

However, the code uses raw pointers to access the same memory concurrently, which is often said to lead to undefined behavior (UB) in Rust due to potential issues like:

Non-atomicity of operations (read-modify-write could interleave unpredictably).
Compiler and CPU optimizations (e.g., instruction reordering, stale cache reads).
Violations of Rust’s aliasing rules for mutable references.

The Question:
Given the logic and the context:

Is this actually undefined behavior according to Rust’s memory model?
Does the presence of non-atomic bitwise operations introduce risks such as memory corruption, crashes, or other undesirable behavior despite the conditional checks in place?
Could compiler or CPU optimizations (e.g., reordering, stale reads, speculative execution) cause this logic to break, even if the program seemingly guarantees mutual exclusivity in updates?

While I understand that using atomics would be the correct way to handle this scenario, I am curious if this specific code, with its eventual consistency model, is truly UB in the technical sense. Would love an explanation based on Rust’s aliasing rules, compiler optimizations, and the underlying hardware behavior.



Is this actually undefined behavior according to Rust’s memory model?


Yes. From std::ptr:

... it is undefined behavior to perform two concurrent accesses to the same location from different threads unless both accesses only read from memory.

Because of this, questions 2 and 3 are irrelevant; any answer given would be nonsense since UB by definition cannot be reasoned about.

It's worth noting, IMO, that Miri can automatically detect this particular UB (error: Undefined Behavior: Data race detected between (1) non-atomic read on thread \unnamed-1` and (2) non-atomic write on thread `unnamed-2` at alloc972. (2) just happened here`)

Well, yes, I understand that the compiler makes an assumption that no two threads concurrently access the same memory location with one of them being a write, but I cannot convince myself that this code is broken, and it's somehow possible to achieve unpredictable results. The data race is there, that is a given, but it doesn't affect the logic of the program....

@BaburMakhmudov It's undefined behavior. "The program works as intended" is one possible outcome, but that outcome is not guaranteed. Once UB is invoked, you completely lose the ability to reason about the behavior of the program. That is not a situation I would want to ever create, especially on purpose. In particular, Google "undefined behavior time travel." In the presence of UB, the compiler is allowed to do entirely nonsensical things.

I understand that UB implies that anything can happen, but I’m just trying to come up with at least one example of what can happen that might lead to unexpected behaviour of this particular program. Otherwise it’s just saying it’s a UB because the rules say so, without giving any explanation of why it is a UB in this particular case.

"but the logic ensures only one thread writes to the memory location at a time, based on a conditional check." this assertion is incorrect, because the operations are non-atomic there is no telling what is in local caches, and it's perfectly possible for both threads to pass the condition and do a write at the same time.

You're trying to play word games with UB, don't do that. It's UB because the rules say it's UB, and trying to reason about "what can happen" in the presence of UB, and even more so concurrency, is a fool's errand: the entire point of UB is there is no telling what can or can't happen, it doesn't owe you anything like logical behaviour of explanations. For all you know the compiler could remove the entire loop, or remove the test, because at a fundamental level your program is invalid.

@BaburMakhmudov "Otherwise it’s just saying it’s a UB because the rules say so, without giving any explanation of why it is a UB in this particular case." No... it's both. The rules say that it's UB, and the reason why it's UB in your case is as stated in the rule: it's possible for the same memory location to be accessed from multiple threads where at least one access isn't a read. Even if we, for the sake of argument, dismiss the possibility of two concurrent writes, a read concurrent with a write is UB.
